# mongodb c api no insert no error

Tags: c, api, mongodb, g-wan

I am trying to connect to mongodb and insert GET parameters, using G-WAN and mongodb's C driver, i successfully connecting to mongodb, but i havent succeeded any data inserts. 
I am using the code

```
mongo_write_concern_init(write_concern);
write_concern->w = 0;
mongo_write_concern_finish(write_concern);
bson b[1];
bson_init( b );
bson_append_new_oid( b, "_id" );
bson_append_string( b, "param1", param1);
bson_append_string( b, "param2", param2);

status = mongo_insert( conn, "mydb.mycol", b , write_concern);
bson_finish( b );
bson_destroy( b );
mongo_write_concern_destroy(write_concern);
```

connection is successfull, i can see it through mongod.log file;

```
[conn36] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[conn36] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:71 0ms
[conn36] end connection 127.0.0.1:50086
```

but nothing else, i cant get any error messages or error log, also on mongodb shell when i call last errors

```
> db.getLastError()
null
```

returns null 
any idea why this happens or any solution you can advice is welcome, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call must be before mongo_insert():

```
bson_finish( b );
```

Otherwise you have an unfinished BSON object here:

```
status = mongo_insert( conn, "mydb.mycol", b , write_concern);
```

So the code should be

```
bson b[1];

/// Init
bson_init( b );
bson_append_new_oid( b, "_id" );
bson_append_string( b, "param1", param1);
bson_append_string( b, "param2", param2);

// Make this complete
bson_finish( b );

/// Insert
status = mongo_insert( conn, "mydb.mycol", b , write_concern);

/// Destroy the BSON obj
bson_destroy( b );
```

Comment: Thank you, i have also figure out that the latest git version of linux c driver of mongodb's write concern function returns always error with my code, so i used v0.5.2 of mongodb c driver, and now i can insert whatever i want.
Just another little thing, i am trying to build a stats server, so i choose mongodb and c, but about 55k request, mongodb started to not to response, its about 10k request per seconds, and that was just a early production test, so i guess i have to switch database server or optimize mongodb for my needs, any suggestions are welcome, thank you